# if-check in HTML gone awry

Tags: html, if-statement

I wrote a short function to do some error checks for a form and am stuck at a portion of code where the final 'elseif' clause in the code below keeps getting executed, even when there is text in the textbox...

could you please advise...thank you..

```
    function errorCheck(){

    if(!isInteger(document.getElementById("appleQty").value)){
    alert('Please key in an integer in the Apple Quantity text box.');
    document.getElementById("appleQty").value="";
    document.getElementById("appleQty").focus();
    return false;

    }
    else if(!isInteger(document.getElementById("orangeQty").value)){
    alert('Please key in an integer in the Orange Quantity text box.');
    document.getElementById("orangeQty").value="";
    document.getElementById("orangeQty").focus();
    return false;
    }
    else if(!isInteger(document.getElementById("bananaQty").value)){
    alert('Please key in an integer in the Banana Quantity text box.');
    document.getElementById("bananaQty").value="";
    document.getElementById("bananaQty").focus();
    return false;

    }
    else if(document.getElementById("user").value = " "){ /!-Problem, keeps getting repeated-->
    document.getElementById("user").focus();
    alert('Please key in your name.');

    return false;


    }
    return true;



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should use `==` to compare, `=` to assign. You are assigning, so add an extra `=` to compare.

Comment: You might want to check for an empty string, `""` instead of `" "` which is a single space.

Answer (score 1):

You are using = as assignment, not equivalence. Use == or ===.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. Use `==` for comparison, not `=`.
2. The empty string is `""`, not `" "`. Notice the extra space.

Result:

```
else if (document.getElementById("user").value == "") {
```